# Android: How can I keep empty EditText fields out of a randomized count?

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, random

I am working on this Android app that has five `EditText` fields in the **first activity**.

Users can fill out any of the `EditText` fields they want and after pressing a `Button`, they'll get a randomized answer on a single `TextView` in the **second activity**.

For example, if the user fills out 2 `EditText` fields, the empty ones are still part of the random count.

Also, whenever a user fills out random `EditText` fields (an example: `choiceThree` and `choiceFour`), nothing gets passed to the **second activity**.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Here's the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText choiceOne;
    EditText choiceTwo;
    EditText choiceThree;
    EditText choiceFour;
    EditText choiceFive;
    Button mainButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        choiceOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputOne);
        choiceTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputTwo);
        choiceThree = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputThree);
        choiceFour = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFour);
        choiceFive = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFive);

        mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inputButton);
        mainButton.setOnClickListener(this);




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

        if(choiceOne.getText().toString() != null && !choiceOne.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        intent.putExtra("choiceOne", choiceOne.getText().toString());
    }

        if(choiceTwo.getText().toString() != null && !choiceTwo.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        intent.putExtra("choiceTwo", choiceTwo.getText().toString());
    }

        if(choiceThree.getText().toString() != null && !choiceThree.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        intent.putExtra("choiceThree", choiceThree.getText().toString());
    }

        if(choiceFour.getText().toString() != null && !choiceFour.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        intent.putExtra("choiceFour", choiceFour.getText().toString());
    }

        if(choiceFive.getText().toString() != null && !choiceFive.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        intent.putExtra("choiceFive", choiceFive.getText().toString());
    }

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();


    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    TextView answerDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        answerDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String[] choice = {intent.getStringExtra("choiceOne"), intent.getStringExtra("choiceTwo"),
                intent.getStringExtra("choiceThree"), intent.getStringExtra("choiceFour"),
                intent.getStringExtra("choiceFive")};
        int choiceRandom = (int) (Math.random()*intent.getExtras().size());

        answerDisplay.setText(choice[choiceRandom]);

    }
```

Comment: see my edited answer and do tell if you are still facing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no input is there in an `EditText`, it doesnt return getText as null, but as `""`.

And in `MainActivity`, work with an `ArrayList` instead of an array.. gives you the option to use the various methods including add and remove.

```
String choiceX = intent.getStringExtra("choiceX");
if(!choiceX.equals("")) {
         choice.add(choiceX);
}
```

for each of the choices. This is the best and easiest way i can see.. :)

Answer (score 1):

put a check in your `onClick` method for each choice, only then save the value in `intent.putExtra()`

```
if(choiceX.getText().toString() != null && !choiceX.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
 intent.putExtra("choiceX", choiceX.getText().toString());
}
```

and then instead of doing `Math.random*5`, use `Math.random*intent.getExtras().size()`

Comment: Somehow, the empty `EditText` fields are still part of the randomized count.  Also, let's say that I fill out `choiceTwo` and `choiceFour` only, nothing gets passed to the **second activity**.  I've updated my code above.  Thanks!

Comment: Here's what I did on the **MainActivity**: `public void onClick(View view)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

        if(choiceOne.getText().toString() != null && !choiceOne.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        intent.putExtra("choiceOne", choiceOne.getText().toString());
    }

        if(choiceTwo.getText().toString() != null && !choiceTwo.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        intent.putExtra("choiceTwo", choiceTwo.getText().toString());
    }` and so forth for each of the choices.

Comment: On the **SecondActivity**: `Intent intent = getIntent();
        String[] choice = {intent.getStringExtra("choiceOne"), intent.getStringExtra("choiceTwo"),
                intent.getStringExtra("choiceThree"), intent.getStringExtra("choiceFour"),
                intent.getStringExtra("choiceFive")};
        int choiceRandom = (int) (Math.random()*intent.getExtras().size());

        answerDisplay.setText(choice[choiceRandom]);` I updated the code on the original question too. It's easier to read there. @sam100rav

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the String you are getting from the Intent is not equal to ""

```
if(!intent.getStringExtra("choiceOne).equals(""))
```

and add only the Strings that are not empty to your String Array. Then you have to get your random number based on how many Strings there are in your Array, by calling *choice.length*.

Comment: Hi Valentin, do I implement this line of code in the **SecondActivity.java**? Still, I can't keep out the empty `EditText` fields out of the randomized count.  For example, I fill out `choiceThree` and `choiceFour` only, nothing gets passed to the second activity.